# Как вписать картинку в канвас, чтобы не было пустой области JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Есть канвас размера 100х100 пикселей и картинка размера 100х80 пикселей. Если ее вставить в канвас, то снизу будет пустая область 100х20 пикселей.
[image]
А как сделать так, чтобы пустой области не было? То есть, чтобы картинка увеличилась и полностью заполнила канвас?
[image]
Есть `object-fit: cover;`, но он изменяет только само отображение картинки, но этого не достаточно, так как потом картинка внутри канваса будет скачиваться. `object-fit: cover;` в данном случае не подходит, потому что при скачивании он не будет учитываться и картинка скачается с пустой областью.

Comment: ты же понимаешь, что при скачивании файла скачается сам файл в исходном размере? и любые манипуляции стилей не причем будут?

Comment: @highpassion да, я об этом и говорю, стили ни на что не повлияют. Есть ли какое-то другое решение?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй создать новое изображение из исходного (исходное можно скрыть, если его не нужно показывать, достаточно, чтобы оно было в DOM) с нужными размерами.

По поводу аргументов для `new Image()` можно прочитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

В твоем случае если тебе нужно растянуть картинку по вертикали, то высчитай высоту канваса и высоту картинки и добавь к высоте новой картинки разницу

```js
const newOne = new Image(200, 400);
newOne.src = document.querySelector('img').src;
document.querySelector('body').append(newOne);
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
```